# Send text from web ASP.NET to Unity 3D Game

Tags: asp.net, unity-game-engine

I have a website made ​​in ASP.NET and want to send some text strings to a game made with Unity 3D, but I found no way to do it. Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: Maybe, to help your searching, you should think of it as Unity downloading strings from your ASP.NET site. There should be enough material available that you can work on this and either solve it or come up with a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Logic**

- Make a common text file [Note Pad].
- From ASP.Net, Send some text strings to **Text file**[Note Pad].
- From Unity, get some text strings from **Text file**[Note Pad].

Make that file in your desired path.